# Exception in Wkhtml2pdf.php line 887: WKHTMLTOPDF didn't return any data in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, wkhtmltopdf, vps, centos6.5

My all PDF working properly in previous server when i transfer my website to VPS it is not working.

Exception in Wkhtml2pdf.php line 887: WKHTMLTOPDF didn't return any data

**in Wkhtml2pdf.php line 887
at Wkhtml2pdf->_render() in Wkhtml2pdf.php line 1030
at Wkhtml2pdf->output('I', 'Leave-2016-11-19 00:01:06.pdf') in Wkhtml2pdf.php line 242**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a long time, i resolve my problem myself.

For LARAVEL.
First open config/Wkhtml2pdf.php file

and

return array(

```
'debug' => false,
'binpath' => 'lib/',
'binfile' => 'wkhtmltopdf-amd64',
'output_mode' => 'I'
```

);

to

return array(

```
'debug' => true,
'binpath' => 'lib/',
'binfile' => 'wkhtmltopdf-amd64',
'output_mode' => 'I'
```

);

And run again in browser.

you see an array like this :

array:3 [▼
  "input" => "/tmp/163448393.html"
  "command" => "/var/www/html/somsv3/vendor/nitmedia/wkhtml2pdf/src/Nitmedia/Wkhtml2pdf/lib/wkhtmltopdf-amd64 --orientation 'Portrait' --page-size 'A4' "/tmp/163448393.html"  -"
  "content" => array:3 [▶]
]

here content is your PDF.

open "content" and fix permission issue of file give it chmod -R 777 "filename"

:)

Comment: Thank you so much using your solution I have solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible error is QT patch missing for `wkhtmltopdf`

Explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64260740/2686510

Solution is to us patched version:

```
wget https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/releases/download/0.12.4/wkhtmltox-0.12.4_linux-generic-amd64.tar.xz
tar xvf wkhtmltox-0.12.4_linux-generic-amd64.tar.xz
mv wkhtmltox/bin/wkhtmlto* /usr/bin/
ln -nfs /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf
```